# No space in username field PFSignUpViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

I am using Parse's built-in signup view controller on iOS, with the PFSignUpViewController.

I don't want that the user can put white space in his username.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the UITextFieldDelegate, like so:

1. Hook up the delegate of your textfield to the PFSignUpViewController, either using storyboard or by finding the name of your UITextField and using the following:

   ```
   usernameTextField.delegate = self;
   ```
2. Make the PFSignUpViewController an implementer of the UITextFieldDelegate on your .h file:

   ```
   PFSignUpViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
   ```
3. Implement the following method to prevent adding whitespace:

   ```
   - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)field shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)characters
   {
       return ([characters [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]].location == NSNotFound);
   }
   ```